# I had errors in MariaDB Event Scheduler

Tags: sql, event-handling, mariadb

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT queue_sorting
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECONDS
    DO
    BEGIN
        DECLARE ts, pn INT;

select  Table_Size_ID INTO ts
    from  Tables
    where  Table_Size_ID = 
      ( SELECT  Table_Size_ID
            from  Queue
            order by  Q_TIME desc
            limit  1
      )
      and  Phone_Number is null
    order by  Table_Line asc, Table_Number asc
    limit  1;


select Phone_Number into pn from Queue order by Q_TIME desc limit 1;

update tables set Phone_Number=pn where Table_Size_ID=ts;


delete from Queue where Phone_Number=pn and Table_Size_ID=ts;

END |

delimiter ;
```

I would love to create an event like this to manage a queue, but the code is errors. I don't know that is why. I have been searching on websites, but I haven't found the best solution. What should I do? Anyone can explain?

Answer (score 0):

What if all the latest Table_Size_ID's had a Phone_Number?  The event cannot move past it to find something useful.

`Table_Size_ID` -- are you normalizing sizes?  (I hope not.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.